# Problem Compiling with link -lstdc++

Tags: g++

I'm new using Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 64-bit). I am trying to learn how to create binary files for a program called Tecplot.

I've been trying to compile the example file simtest.f90, using this:

```
$ gfortran -fcray-pointer -lstdc++ simtest.f90 tecio64.a
```

When I do this, I get a huge list of errors like this:

> tecio.a(tecxxx.o).gnu.linkonce.d.DW.ref.__gxx_pe
>   rsonality_v0[DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0]+0x0): undefined reference to
>   '__gxx_personality_v0'
>   tecio.a(TranslatedString.o).gnu.linkonce.d._ZTIN
>   7tecplot7strutil16TranslatedStringE[typeinfo for
>   tecplot::strutil::TranslatedString]+0x0): undefined reference to
>   `vtable for _*cxxabiv1::*_class_type_info'

I've been reading several forums, and it looks like this is the kind of error you get when you don't link the libstdc++ library (in fact, if I remove the link -lstdc++ I get the exact same error).

If anyone can help me, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `lstdc++` flag to work, you'll need to install a C++ compiler. Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install g++
```